# No module named 'config'

Tags: python

Please feel free to answer this rookie mistake.

I have 2 files named config.py and app.py. In my config.py I have only a dictionary named firebaseConfig. I am trying to use it in my app.py

this is what my config.py looks like

```
firebaseConfig = {
    //contains details of firebase configuration
}
```

and in my app.py I am trying to import it

```
   from firebase import Firebase
   from config import firebaseConfig 
   firebase = Firebase(firebaseConfig)
```

But I am getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.config` because you are importing from a file in the same directory. Which is a relative import.
It should be something like this

```
from .config import firebaseConfig
```

When using `config` python thinks that the module is a global module and it does not look in the same directory
For more info on how import works visit the official docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)